# install Ansible on Centos 6.9

Tags: centos, ansible, yum

i have a machine with CentOS 6.9 as OS and it is minimal. i was trying to install Ansible on my machine. i can't connect my machine to internet to set repository and install Ansible so i downloaded `ansible.tar.gz`. what shoud i do to install it?
the content of tar file:

```
  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 bin
  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 changelogs
  drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 contrib
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 35148 Mar 14 22:33 COPYING
  drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 docs
  drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 examples
  drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 lib
  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 licenses
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 13416 Mar 14 22:33 Makefile
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root   759 Mar 14 22:33 MANIFEST.in
  drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 packaging
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  7298 Mar 14 22:33 PKG-INFO
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  4752 Mar 14 22:33 README.rst
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root   371 Mar 14 22:33 requirements.txt
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 10714 Mar 14 22:33 setup.py
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  3624 Mar 14 22:33 shippable.yml
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  5565 Mar 14 22:33 SYMLINK_CACHE.json
  drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root  4096 Mar 14 22:33 test
  -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1129 Mar 14 22:33 tox.ini
```

i tried to install epel then install ansible but i had no success:

```
 rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: `rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` won't work. First read readme, it will explain installation steps. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html

Comment: @MostafaZare i read its README before but there is no explanation. and the link you refer to is installation with epel repo and yum. am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html). It explained how to install by building it yourself at the end of [this part](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#latest-release-via-dnf-or-yum).

> You can also build an RPM yourself. From the root of a checkout or
>   tarball, use the `make rpm` command to build an RPM you can distribute
>   and install.
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
> cd ./ansible
> make rpm
> sudo rpm -Uvh ./rpm-build/ansible-*.noarch.rpm
> ```